Найти индекс выбранной радиокнопки


$('.step_1').each(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    step1 = $(this).index();
    console.log(step1);
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
            <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
        </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
            <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
        </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
            <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
        </label>
  </div>
</div>



Консоль показывает только одни нули. Нужно найти индекс выбранной радиокнопки с классом step_1. Как это сделать?

Перенес вопрос на лругую ссылку  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1578108/%d0%9f%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8

С помощью forEach для каждой радиокнопки назначаете слушатель события, который при клике выведет в консоль индекс кнопки:


const step = document.querySelectorAll('.step_1');

step.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(index)
  })
});
<div class="radios">
<div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
</div>
</div>




У Jquery есть метод index. Можно использовать его:


$('.step_1').on('click', function() {  
    console.log($('.step_1').index(this));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="step_radio">
        <input class="step_1" type="radio" name="step_1" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>



